# What about Android App Bundles' language support?

Tags: google-play-store, apk, downloading

You can find out everything you need to know about [Android App Bundles here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/). As this is a new way to deliver apk's I am very interested in how it works.

When taking a look at the explanatory video provided on the [linked site](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/) you will understand that the App Bundle will only send the appropriate *language resource files* on download from **Google Play**.

*Now, what happens* when I change the system language **after installation**? Will the application not translate even if in the original *App Bundle* there was my language packaged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a [Google I/O '18](https://youtu.be/0raqVydJmNE?t=12m52s) talk *Google Play* will download all "*typically used languages*" and retrieve others on demand.

> In the rare case, where a user switches to a new language that we weren't aware of before, Play will dynamically deliver relevant splits to their device. (https://youtu.be/0raqVydJmNE?t=13m9s)

Comment: Is there documentation about this? Can a programmer provide functionality that lets the user change the language from within the app and only for that app?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your app supports two languages English And Spanish.

***Case 1*** :
You are uploading **APK** both languages will be shipped it is upto user to select what they want to use.

***Case 2***:
You know that certain user will always use Spanish so rather than whole package apk you can send **Bundle** with spanish support only.

If you have shipped app with Spanish but user wants English google will dynamically ship those split apks for English.

But if user opts for French it won't be supported since your app have English and Spanish support only user can use third party if they want to translate.

**Answer** :

Yes , if you're app has support for that language google will ship it even if it is not in bundle.

No , if you don't have support for selected language.

Comment: In the I/O session I linked in my answer they stated something different. They said that they would be downloaded after installation automatically.

Comment: Thanks @creativecreatormaybenot for pointing out mistake, I have rectified the answer.